# where to store Serial number in an embedded system running fedora 11

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

I have a task to accept serial number in Json format and validate it using C++ and store it  and user is not allowed to change it. Only production team needs to change it. Now my question is where would I saved or stored the serial number . The product is an embedded system and run via complact flash card .

The product is embedded system  run on Fedora system and it is not trial version. The user will buy the whole product and only production team are allowed to assign serial number to individual product. In  case of software crash or upgration we dont want to loose serial number.

Thanks and regards,
Sam

Comment: Could some one please expalin whats wrong with the question so that I can be careful next time

Comment: You need to provide more detail on the layout of your system, and what sort of access the user has.

Comment: well this issue has been solved. To store serial number I am using I2C memory chip  that communicates with FTDI chip over I2C bus.  Thanks a lot to everyone for there suggestion

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea about the architecture of the system that you are using; its memory map, any protected flash resources that you have available.

When storing serial number type information I normally ensure the following:

1. The item to be stored is held in its own flash sector.
2. This sector is not visible to any normal flash erasure code
3. Before writing a value, the serial number sector must be blank (no serial number assigned to the unit before).  Attempting to rewrite the data is rejected.
4. A CRC is added to the serial number data for validation.

All of the processors that I have used have a small amount of configuration or information flash that can be used for calibration values etc.  I use some of this memory as a write once serial number store.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming users are not able to access your system (or at least not as root), a simple file in /etc/ might do.
This also rather assumes you don't overwrite the entire flash when (if?) you upgrade the software.